# Basin of attraction

Tags: plotting

How to write the program of basin for the system of equations. Please help me if anybody have some idea. Equations are `x^2+y-1==0`, `x+y+1==0`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried already? What didn't work? The more specific you can be -- and the more you can show you've tried to solve your own problem -- the more willing people will be to offer their help.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a dynamical system? I don't see any derivatives.

Comment: Please, share your definintion of a basin of attraction of a system of equations with us.

Comment: For these equations write the program of basin of attraction by using  Newton method x_(k+1)=x_k-f(x_k)/f'(x_k)